# Renaming a HTML file with Python

Tags: python, html

A bit of background:
When I save a web page from e.g. IE8 as "webpage, complete", the images and such that the page contains are placed in a subfolder with the postfix "_files". This convention allows Windows to synchronize the .htm file and the accompanying folder.

Now, in order to keep the synchronization intact, when I rename the HTML file from my Python script I want the "_files" folder to be renamed also. Is there an easy way to do this, or will I need to
- rename the .htm file
- rename the _files folder
- parse the .htm file and replace all references to the old _files folder name with the new name?

Comment: In Perl, there is a module for that, I am pretty sure :-), although I guess you have to write your own in Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is just one easy way: Have IE save the file again under the new name. But if you want to do it later, you must parse the HTML. In this case, [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

If you rename the folder, I'm not sure how you can get around parsing the `.htm` file and replacing instances of `_files` with the new suffix. Perhaps you can use a folder alias (shortcut?) but then that's not a very clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can use simple string replace on your HTML file without parsing it, it can of course be troublesome if the text being replaced is mentioned in the HTML itself..

```
os.rename("test.html", "test2.html")
os.rename("test_files", "test2_files")

with open("test2.html", "r") as f:
     s = f.read().replace("test_files", "test2_files")

with open("test2.html", "w") as f:
     f.write(s)
```